# Create STANDALONE Android Studio (1.5) library project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I need to create an **Android Library** and deliver the final .***jar*** file to the clients.

I am new to Android development (three days). I've been developing iOS for the last 4 years. I went through Google's official documentation and tutorials to get a feel for the platform (I don't want it to be obvious that an iOS guy was writing the library).

I don't have any problems with Java, but I do with Android. I decided to go with Android Studio since it is the official IDE. I am using version *1.5*.

***PROBLEM:***

So as I said, I need to create an Android Library and deliver the .***jar*** file to the clients. I would like this Android Studio project to be a **standalone library project with its own unit tests**. I don't want to create an unnecessary *App* project, and then add an *Android Library* module to it. I want to create a **separate** *App* project which will include this .***jar*** file, so I can test it in the way it will reach our clients.

I've seen a lot of options online for how to accomplish this, but all of them seem a bit "hacky" (e.g. rename this folder, change that app-project-setting and make it a library project). Is there no way to create a Library project from a new project wizard in Android Studio?

What are your suggestions on how I should proceed with this? Is there some elegant solution to this without these tricks to re-configure the App project?

***EDIT***

Here is what the new project wizard looks like:
[image]

[image]

I select "Add no activity" here
[image]

Comment: I seem to remember reading that if you uncheck all of the options on the Target Android Devices screen, it won't create the `app` module.  Then you don't have to delete anything before creating the module type that you actually wanted.  (Not posting this as an answer because I don't use Android Studio, precisely because of stupid things like this.)

Comment: @Kevin Krumwiede - it doesn't appear so. a message appears in red at the bottom of the dialogue letting you know that "At least one form factor must be selected".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This may not feel comfortable for a person from other platform/IDE/world, but this is The Way. Personally i'm getting annoyed with Xcode every time i use it in the exact same way you're annoyed with AndroidStudio now. But lets get down to business:

1. Create an empty project and select "Create no activity".
   [image]
2. When everything is set, go to "File\New\New Module" and select "Android Library"
   [image]
3. Give a name for created library and click "Finish".
4. (Optional) go to "Run\Edit Configurations" and set everything like below:
   [image]
5. Now open the librarie's 'build.gradle' file. Make sure to open the file from exact same folder which is named with your library name, because there are a couple of 'build.gradle' files all over the place. Remove support-library entry from the file:
   [image]
6. Write some code and when you're ready to deploy the library set everything like this:
   [image]

Go to "Build" menu at the top and select "Build APK".

And about unit tests:
[image]

**Edit 1: **

If you really want to remove the 'app' folder, than follow instructions on a picture below:
[image]

Comment: So there is no way to avoid creating of "app" folder?

Comment: So I got the AAR file now. How can I use it in my current project? Import it with Graddle ?

Comment: Thank you. There is no option in Android Studio 1.5.1 to "Remove module" when right clicking it from within the Library project.. I don't specifically need it gone, but it would be clean if it were.

Comment: very nice tutorial! To be honest, I've used several IDE's in my time and when starting a new project, there has always been an option such as "Library Project [ ]". a checkbox like this would definitely be user-friendly to have on the "New Project" screen in Android Studio

Comment: @Mullazman After you have the 'app' entry removed from the 'settings.gradle' file, and AS rebuilds a project, the 'app' folder is not considered as a part of the project anymore. You could notice this because the 'app' label font becomes not bold. After that you can remove this folder in any way you prefer: either directly from the file system by using a file manager, or by right clicking in AS project view and choosing 'Delete'.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **Library Project** instead of Normal Project,then your output product will be a jar or aar as you configured.If your library has resources then build it as aar,or it will be jar.

When you created a project as yo are doing,click File->new Module,then will like this:

[image]

If your library project have resources or will use API of Android,then choose **Android Library**,else choose **Java Library**,Android Library will build aar as product whild Java Library build jar product.

Comment: I edited my question with the screenshots of Android Studio project wizard.

Comment: Firstly,you create a project as you just doing,when this done,create a new module which type is library Project